# call pageReference method in test class (there is only class no any vfpage)

Tags: unit-test, pagereference

call pageReference method in test class (there is only class no any vfpage)

```
 public Pagereference pgredir(){
    String RT = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().Get('RecordType');
String url = '/' + Case.SObjectType.GetDescribe().GetKeyPrefix() + '/e?RecordType=' + RT + '&nooverride=1
    return new ApexPages.PageReference(url).SetRedirect(true);
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how to call page Reference method in test class i want to cover pgredir method in test class

Comment: PageReference is just the return type. You can call a method that returns a PageReference just like you would call any other method:     `ClassName cls = new ClassName();
    cls.pgredir();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `test.setCurrentPage()` in your test class in a way something like this

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.success;//Observe how we set the Page here
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);//Applying page context here
```

Below post has a detailed explaination on how to use this

[Why use Test.setCurrentPage() method in a unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/74043/why-use-test-setcurrentpage-method-in-a-unit-test)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `PageReference` if you have any VF page and then set Page Parameters. Try below code:

```
static testmethod void testFoo() {

        test.startTest();
        ControllerName tc =new ControllerName ();

        // if you have any VF page else ignore below two lines
        PageReference pageRefer = Page.PageName;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRefer)

        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('RecordType','XYZ');
        PageReference pg = tc.pgredir();        
        test.stopTest();


    }
```

Replace `ControllerName` with your class Name. This will cover all the lines of your function.

Answer (score 0):

It is common for controllers to reference parameters that are passed in the URL so tests for such controllers need to set parameter values. Sp in your test method you would have e.g.:

```
PageReference pr = Page.YourPageName;
pr.getParameters().put('RecordType', '...');
Test.setCurrentPage(pr);
```

before you create your controller class and invoke its methods.