# Unittest eror: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, unit-test, list, pagereference, get

I am writing a unittest for my apex class but get an error System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object on my unittest for variable: testoptions

Apex class

```
public class WebToObjAttachments {
    public date TravelDateIn {get;set;}
    public date TravelDateOut {get;set;}

    public class ApplicationException extends Exception {}
    private final Lead weblead;
    public string recordtype{get;set;}
    public List<Attachment> attachments {get; set;} 
    public List<Attachment> newAttachments {get; set;}
    public string recordtypetext {get;set;}
    public blob file { get; set; }
    public string urlvalue=Apexpages.currentPage().getUrl();
        ..
            public List<SelectOption> CountryOptions {
            get {
                    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
                if(!urlvalue.contains('_NL')){
                    options.add(new SelectOption('NL', 'Netherlands')); 
                    for (Schema.PicklistEntry pe : SObjectType.Lead.fields.CountryCode.getPicklistValues()) {

                    }
                    options.add(new SelectOption('BE', 'Belgium')); 
                    options.add(new SelectOption('FR', 'France')); 
                    options.add(new SelectOption('DE', 'Germany')); 
                    options.add(new SelectOption('ES', 'Spain')); 
                    options.add(new SelectOption('PT', 'Portugal')); 
                    options.add(new SelectOption('IT', 'Italy')); 
                    options.add(new SelectOption('GB', 'United Kingdom')); 
                    options.add(new SelectOption('SCOT', 'Scotland')); 
                    options.add(new SelectOption('IE', 'Ireland')); 
                    options.add(new SelectOption('US', 'United States')); 
                }
             return options;
    } 
        set;}
        ..
        }
```

Unittest

```
 private static testMethod void CountryOptionsTest()
{
    property__c prop = new property__c();
    prop.name = 'Testproperty';
    insert prop;

    Lead le=new Lead(Lastname='Unit Test', RecordType__c = 'Guest');
    insert le;
    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(le);
    WebToObjAttachments controller = new WebToObjAttachments(sc);
    PageReference pageRef = Page.WebToObjAttachment_NL;

    Test.startTest();
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
    List<SelectOption> testoptions = controller.CountryOptions ; 
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Bebug on urlvalue returms null what am I doing wrong.

> Blockquote

Comment: I assume that *urlvalue* is null since there are no Test.setPage() in the unit test, therefore it is not being set and it cause null pointer exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done in your test class is instatiate your apex controller, but you haven't provided any context for that controller. In other words, your `getURL()` in the controller is based on the current page and you need to set this in your unit test. This [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/74043/why-use-test-setcurrentpage-method-in-a-unit-test) goes over why you need to use it as you might have a single controller for different pages. You want to set the context and test for the behavior you're expecting from the controller for a specific page.

You can do this by creating a [PageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm) with your Visualforce page

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.VisualforcePageName;
```

and then setting that as the current page in test using [setCurrentPage()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm).

```
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
```

After you've done the two things above, you can do what you were doing (ApexPages.standardController and instantiating your controller)

Comment: I updated my test as you suggested but stil get the same error.

Comment: You need to make the PageReference and Test.setCurrentPage lines occur first, before the controller line as the controller relies on the current page being set already.